# validation on phone 01x-xxxxxxxx jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm validating the form with jQuery Validate.

To validate the phone number field I do:

phone number should written  as  01x-xxxxxxxx

```
var phonereg = /^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{7}$/;
```

But I need to check also that phone starts with 01.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hey, why did you undo my formatting? I'm not going to fix it again, you're on your own.

Comment: wanna the first part start with 01

Comment: Do you want the part after the dash to be seven digits as in your regex, or eight digits as in your question title and description?

Answer (score 3):

If it has to start with `01`, put that at the beginning of the RE:

```
var phonereg = /^01\d-\d{7}$/;
```